# how to check if sqlite database is empty (android)?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making a media player which loads metadata of songs into a database.
Below is my function for checking whether the db is empty or not but it isn't working. Please tell me what's wrong with my code and suggest a correction or a better alternative.

```
private static boolean isDbEmpty(SQLiteDatabase songsDb) {
    try {
        Cursor c = songsDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SongsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {    // c.getCount() == 0  is also not working
            Log.d(TAG, "isDbEmpty: not empty");
            return false;
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "isDbEmpty: doesn't exist");
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `c.getCount() == 0  is also not working` what problem you are getting?

Comment: The code looks mostly OK; the problem is likely to be your data.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK c.getCount() returns 169 even when there are no entries in the db. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query to achieve your goal. There are two tables created automatically - android_metadata and sqlite_sequence, so we apply a NOT condition in the query.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'android_metadata' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private static boolean isDbEmpty(SQLiteDatabase songsDb) {
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = songsDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SongsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);
        if (c == null || c.getCount() == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "isDbEmpty: not empty");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "isDbEmpty: doesn't exist");
        return true;
    }finally {
        if(c != null){
            c.close();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: IMO you can use the `finally` block to close the Cursor rather putting it inside in the `catch` block,`conditions` or outside the scope of `try-catch` block.

Comment: @Enzokie Actually wouldn't that mess with the return statements?

Comment: Nice edit but you can minimize it a bit like [this](https://hastebin.com/taruxaqupu.swift)

Comment: that looks great now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132390/discussion-between-enzokie-and-danieboy).

Comment: @Enzokie I just realised something... won't if (c == null || c.getCount() == 0) get a nullPointerException if c == null? Because it will still check the second part..right? So maybe that should actually be split up.

Comment: No it wont, because if ever `c==null` returns true the `c.getCount==0` will no longer be called.

Comment: @Danieboy I'm not getting any error but the code isn't working the way it's supposed to. It always returns false (isDbEmpty: not empty).

Answer (score -1):

This will only tell you if the `TABLE` is empty, not the `DATABASE`.

Regardless, you could use code like:

```
Cursor countCursor = songsDb.rawQuery("select count(*) from " + SongsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);
countCursor.moveToFirst();
int count = countCursor.getInt(0);
countCursor.close();
```

And then test `count`.

Answer (score -1):

You can check like this :

```
Cursor c = songsDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SongsTable.TABLE_NAME, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() == 0) {
     //for empty
        return true;
    }else{
    // not empty
    return false;
  }
```